# Array of Results<> changing its element positions after deletion using Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am using realm to handle persistent data from the array:

```
var listArray: Results<Category>?
```

When I delete the first element of listArray, the last element of my array is moved to position 0. Is there a way to change this, so that each element moves to occupy the "position-1", instead?

Here's an example of what is happening:

listArray before deleting first item ("Item 0"):

```
Optional(Results<Category> <0x7f89dd637250> (
[0] Category {
    listName = Item 0;
    categoryColorHex = #EDF1F2;
    items = List<Item> <0x600001dd9b00> (

    );
},
[1] Category {
    listName = Item 1;
    categoryColorHex = #E57D22;
    items = List<Item> <0x600001dd8a20> (

    );
},
[2] Category {
    listName = Item 2;
    categoryColorHex = #A38570;
    items = List<Item> <0x600001dd8fc0> (

    );
}
))
```

After deleting "Item 0":

```
Optional(Results<Category> <0x7f89dd637250> (
    [0] Category {
        listName = Item 2;
        categoryColorHex = #A38570;
        items = List<Item> <0x600001dd9050> (

        );
    },
    [1] Category {
        listName = Item 1;
        categoryColorHex = #E57D22;
        items = List<Item> <0x600001ddb840> (

        );
    }
))
```

As you can see, Item 2, which was the last element in my array, is now occupying the first position.
Here's the code to delete things:

```
if listArray?[indexPath.row] != nil {
    do {
        try self.realm.write {
            self.realm.delete(listArray![indexPath.row])
        }} catch {
            print("error at editActionsForRowAt: \(error)")
    }
    //print("\(listArray) \n \n")
}
```

Other operations (Saving and loading) are working just fine in realm.

Regards,
FS

Comment: On remove, array gets re-assigned with the remaining elements and you should sort yourself if you need a sorted result.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you call `sorted(byKeyPath:)` on a `Results` instance, the ordering of the elements isn't guaranteed to be kept after the `Results` auto-updates.

So in order to achieve your goals, you need to sort your `Results` instance based on one of the properties of `Category`.